# A neat way to create time series with categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

Given a list of tuples, each tuple is of (date-time, lang, type) where lang takes three possible values (say 'en', 'es', and 'ja') and type takes two values: 'U' or 'R'.

I want to create a data frame for time series with the following columns:
day, language, 'U', and 'R'.
That is, lang, U, and R are counted per day per language.

Example, given a list of records (of tupples):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records, columns=['time','lang','type'])
df.head()
```

Results in:

```
     time                  lang  type
0    2016-05-19 20:20:26    en    R
1    2016-05-19 20:20:43    ja    R
2    2016-05-19 20:26:01    ja    U
3    2016-05-19 20:30:31    en    R
4    2016-05-19 20:33:57    es    R
...
```

And I want to manipulate this dataframe (or the original list of records) get something like this:

```
time        lang  U    R
2016-05-19  en     4    2
            ja     1    1
            es     0    1
2016-05-20  en    10    7
            ja     1    9
            es     3   13
```

I'm trying to do this with

```
df2 = df.groupby([df['time'].dt.to_period('D'), 'lang', 'type']).count().unstack()
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(0)
```

But I get an index at the column and I can't get rid of it (ignore the numbers).

```
            type    U     R
time        lang
2016-05-19    en     4    2
              ja     1    1
              es     0    1
2016-05-20    en    10    7
              ja     1    9
              es     3   13
```

and

```
df2.columns
```

returns: Index([u'R', u'U'], dtype='object', name=u'type')

Any idea as of how to create the desired with no extra fluff?

Answer (score 2):

`"type"` remains as the name of the columns. You can remove it this way:

```
df2.columns.name = None
```

However, I don't think you can have the 4 other labels on the same linebecause the first two labels are the multiindex on the row, and the 2 others are a simple index on the columns.

Comment: Thanks! indeed that works to reduce the multi-index. I rebuilt it from the records in a slightly different way to avoid it - grouping an counting in a dictionary on the fly. It's also more efficient.